# Can I use floor() to specific numbers?

Tags: r, rounding, floor

I want to `floor()` to the next specific number (not a number of digits, but actual values).
E.g. for a list of years:

```
valid_years = c(1990,2000,2006,2012,2018) # values to round to ("snap")

input  = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2006, 2007, 2016, 2020)
output = c(1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2006, 2006, 2012, 2018)
```

The behavior for inputs below (or in case of `ceil()` above) the specified values is not important for me. A good behavior in my case would be to snap to the lowest value in `valid_years`, however it is not important to me.

I know I could achieve this with if-then-else (e.g. `if(x < 2006) x = 2000 else if(x < 2012) x = 2006 ...`) , but I am sure there are more elegant ways to solve this.

I have browsed many "rounding in R" questions, but haven't found an answer despite many similarily phrased questions, which all have their unique (different) goal: e.g. [rounding to specific decimal-steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58825946/how-to-round-to-specific-decimal-numbers-in-r),
[rounding to arbitrary number within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861061/round-to-nearest-arbitrary-number-from-list) or [conditional rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818848/round-conditionally-numbers-in-r).

Comment: You can play with `cut` function. A start would be `cut(input, breaks = c(-Inf, 1990, 2000, 2006, 2012, 2018, Inf), right = FALSE)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `findInterval`:

```r
valid_years[findInterval(input, valid_years)]
#  [1] 1990 1990 1990 1990 2000 2000 2000 2006 2006 2012 2018
all(valid_years[findInterval(input, valid_years)] == output)
#  [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Nice, that is the "elegant" I was hoping for and it works for single numbers as well as vectors: `valid_years[findInterval(2017, valid_years)]`. This implements floor() perfectly, inputs < valid_years will result in `valid_years[findInterval(1989, valid_years)] = numeric(0)`, whereas inputs > valid_years are no problem (2024 = 2018). I'm curios: Is this easy to remodel to a ceil()-behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
purrr::map_dbl(input, ~ tail(valid_years[valid_years <= .x], 1))
```

Result:

```
 [1] 1990 1990 1990 1990 2000 2000 2000 2006 2006 2012 2018
```

Answer (score 1):

For a base R solution with functions (Hope I've commented enough):

```
nearest <- function(samples, value) {
  # Return index of minimal absolute difference between samples and the value provided
  which.min(abs(samples - value))
}

round_to_values <- function(desired, input) {
  # Init the resulting vector to avoid growing within the loop
  results = input
  # Loop over the input values and fill result with the index of the nearest desired vector
  for (i in seq(1, length(input))) {
    results[i] = desired[nearest(desired, input[i])]
  }
  # return the results
  results
}

# Effectively call the function witht the inputs
valid_years = c(1990,2000,2006,2012,2018) # values to round to ("snap")
input  = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2006, 2007, 2016, 2020)

round_to_values(valid_years, input)
```

Result is:

```
> round_to_values(valid_years, input)
 [1] 1990 1990 1990 1990 2000 2000 2000 2006 2006 2018 2018
```

Comment: Rounding, not floor :/ missed part of the question.